# What is best practice for creating an Ember form with live validation?

Tags: devise, ember.js

I have a user registration form written in Ember + Handlebars. I'm new to both. I would like to perform live validation on the form while users type. For this I need to be able to watch for change events and respond intelligently.

I was thinking I could declare an `email` attribute in my view and watch it for changes. Then ask the server if that `email` already existed.

I can think of a few ways to do this, but can't see a clear winner. I've tried observing changes on the view as a whole, but that seems clunky. Now I'm attempting to create a `new-user` object and store the logic in there, but Ember wants to connect that back to the server. I'm a bit at a loss here.

Any advice would be welcome.

This is where my view is right now:

```
FitMap.JoinView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "join",

  name: null,
  email: null,
  password: null,
  password_confirmation: null,

  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $.post("/users", {
      name: this.get("name"),
      email: this.get("email"),
      password: this.get("password"),
      password_confirmation: this.get("password_confirmation")
    }, function() {
      console.log("created");
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in this way

```
FitMap.JoinView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "join",
  name: null,
  email: null,
  password: null,
  password_confirmation: null,
  didInsertElement: function() {
      var frm = $("#" + this.elementId);
      frm.validate({rules: ...});
  },
  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var frm = $("#" + this.elementId);
    if (!frm.valid()) {
        console.log("form is not in a valid state");
        return false;
    }
  })
});
```

jQuery validation let you define inside the rules a remote validation, I'm exactly using it to check if the username/email is already in use.

Comment: I came across [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) after posting and started to try and utilize that. If it doesn't pan out, it's good to know jQuery has something for me as well. Thanks!